# How to protect drop down menus in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-protection

I want to make a google sheet, where multiple users can select a value from a drop down menu, and not do anything else (like adding other values, deleting content etc.).

I have made this solution with data validation (4 options, color coded).  All good, but:  if I protect the cells, users can't enter data.  If I do not protect the cells, users can actually delete the content of the cell (the drop down menu disappears).

Any other/smarter way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Your post is an exact copy of [Protecting data validated cells](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/237564134). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I don't really understand (maybe just a bug?), Google have set up data validation such that the new 'chip' style drop-downs can be deleted just by pressing delete on the keyboard if the cell is empty, **whereas** if you use the older 'arrow' style (found in 'advanced options') this is not the case; this style of data validation can only be deleted by going into the data validation menu and deleting it from the list there (i.e. it can't be done by accident).

Comment: Might be worth noting that while the `Dropdown` with `Display style=Chip` can be deleted when empty, neither `Arrow` ***nor*** `Plain text` can be.